# Why does boto3 head_object doesn't return metadata even if it exists?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using head_object to retrieve metadata like so (to detect if it's my first time uploading this file):

```py
def obj_exists(bucket, key):
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    exists = True
    try:
        res = s3_client.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        m = res["Metadata"]
        is_first_time = m.get("first") == None
        if is_first_time:
            m["first"] = "true"
            
            result = s3_client.copy_object(
                Bucket = bucket,
                Key = key,
                CopySource = bucket + '/' + key,
                Metadata = m,
                MetadataDirective='REPLACE'
            )
            
            print("RESULT", result)

            exists = False
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        exists = False
    
    return exists
```

I know that the metadata exists for the given object key.

```
x-amz-meta-first: "true"
```

When i run test lambda from console manually, i'm able to get the metadata with `s3_client.head_object`

But when the **lambda** was invoked by a **CloudWatch** event, i'm not able to get any metadata.

Whats the reason of that? 
Thanks.

Comment: Missing permissions!? What data do you actually get? What output does the lambda produce?

Comment: RequestId, VersionId, LastModified, Metadata etc,
but Metadata is an empty object {}. 

Even tho Metadata does exist.

Comment: Can you post the full code snippet of your lambda function?

Comment: At point does your lambda get triggered, by what cloud watch logic? Is the metadata certainly set already at that point?

Comment: my lambda does get triggered once we upload a file to s3 (put)

If it's triggered by cloudwatch then İ can't get metadata info no matter what but once i trigger it manually it's the opposite.

Comment: Can you check if your key has any whitespaces? The trigger replaces ' ' with + when it sends you the key

Comment: i double checked, everything i send manually and what's sent from CloudWatch event is exactly the same.